# NodeJS, Protractor and Chrome DevTools Error

Tags: node.js, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get Protractor E2E testing to run on my local Windows workstation at work but I keep getting this error.

> webpack: Compiled successfully. [07:50:41] I/file_manager - creating
>   folder
>   c:\repos\polo-buyer-ui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
>   [07:50:42] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.32.zip
>   [07:50:44] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver [07:50:44]
>   I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
>   [0925/075047.256:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(786)] DevTools
>   listening on 127.0.0.1:12985

I am able to get it to work with no issues on a linux workstation and my personal (non-work) PC runnning Windows 10.  I find very little information on this error message

> [0925/075047.256:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(786)] DevTools

But I get this no matter what I do and I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing below steps:-

Open cmd and in the home path use below commands.

1. webdriver-manager clean
2. webdriver-manager status
3. webdriver-manager update
4. webdriver-manager start.

Answer (score 0):

could  you please check whether your laptop has any encryption in the system. Few of these encryptions corrupt the node modules , which results in the failure of the test cases.

This is the only reason I could guess since you ran all your test cases earlier
To verify this you could uninstall all the npm files and re-install them again and then re-run your test cases without re-starting your PC

PS : I faced the same issue and we asked IT team to remove encryption for just one folder which will contain all the automation code